# How to add a site that uses java to the Java exception list in JDK 11?

Tags: java, exception, configuration, java-11

In the previous versions of Jdk (7-10) there was a java console, where we could add  sites in Security->ExceptionSites. In JDK 11 Java Control Panel, which was used for configuring the deployment technologies, has been removed along with the shared system JRE (but not the server JRE) and the JRE Auto Update mechanism.

How can I make my app work ?

Thank you!

Comment: seems like the deployment tutorial is gone too - have to use `jlink` to create an executable... [:-|